# Modify a string array for it to be used as an id in targeting

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've been fiddling with this trying to use splice and join method but can't seem to get the effect that I really want.

I want to put a number sign (#) right before the strings. so I could use those array in targeting for jQuery. I can't edit the array and manually place the hastag because the array will come somewhere else.

my code is something like this:

```
$(function(){

    var arr = ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3'];
    // I want to convert it from 'item-1, item-2, item-3' to '#item-1, #item-2, #item-3'

    $(arr).css({ 'border', 'red solid 1px'})

});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6EkKe/

Comment: `$("#" + arr.join(",#"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to necessarily edit the array, instead you can add to the values before you use them in Jquery.
**Individual items**

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

$(arr).each(function(key, value)){
    var id = '#' + value;
    $(id).css({ 'border', 'red solid 1px'});
});
```

**Using them all at the same time**

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var ids = '#' + arr.join(', #');
$(ids).css({ 'border', 'red solid 1px'});
```

**Explanation**
[Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) takes a parameter, this parameter is a string that will be put in between each of the array element, if left blank it will use `''`

Comment: oh, I see, got it. The explanation cleared it up for me. Thank you!